# Having trouble running Firefox on Linux remotely

Tags: linux, ssh, firefox, xorg, xming

I am having trouble running Firefox on Linux remotely.

When I use PuTTY and X11 to ssh remotely into a stand-alone Oracle Linux 8 box on my local network and run Firefox, the app comes up and hangs; completely unresponsive.

I ended up having to kill it with the Windows Task Manager, which kills the XMing/XLaunch instance it was running in on my Windows 7 client, along with any other GUI apps that were running under that. Other GUIs (like the Oracle database installer) have run successfully.

When I log onto the Linux box directly and run Firefox, it runs with no problems.

When I use PuTTY and X11 to ssh remotely into a VirtualBox Oracle Linux 8 instance running on my same Windows 7 host, it runs slower than if I run it directly on the VirtualBox, but it runs, and is usable.

The stand-alone Linux machine is an 8 year-old Lenovo t420s laptop with 8GB RAM.

The Windows 7 machine is a 4 year-old Lenovo T460p laptop with 32 GB RAM; The Linux VirtualBox running on it has 8GB RAM allocated.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I wiped out the Linux stand-alone box, re-installed Linux, and re-installed the oracle database. Firefox works without hanging...sometimes.  When it gets intolerably sluggish, I shutdown the database and/or reboot the OS. 
Luckily this is a Dev sandbox machine so it doesn't matter too much. For a real Linux server that would need to stay up and perform, I guess I need a more powerful and up-to-date machine with at least 16 GB RAM.
Cheers,
Howard